# Changing location of model checkpoints in Hugging Face

Tags: huggingface

I'm downloading a big model. I've changed to a new external data storage device which has a enough space with `export HF_HOME='\blah\blah'`. However when it comes to downloading that model, I get the following error, which appears like the checkpoint is not able to be stored:

```
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/Volumes/hdd_ext/cache/hub/tmpft8xst3n' -> 'checkpoints/ckpt-0/tensor00000_000'
```

How can I fix this?